# Axios, request: cannot ignore socket hang up (ECONNRESET) error

Tags: node.js, request, axios

I'm working on a web scraping software using axios and libraries on node.js. Here is part of the code.

The problem is, I cannot pass through `Error: socket hang up` error specifically. When other errors happend, for example, `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`, `Error: Request failed with status code 404`, `Error: Request failed with status code 403`, `Error: unable to verify the first certificate`, the script pass through these errors and proceed the next URLs with no issue. However, seemingly some site causes `Error: socket hang up` error and the error makes the script exit with exit code of 0 (success).

I have no clue what is happening around the error, why the only error causes the script end, and no detailed error info or errored exit code. How can I prevent the script from exiting because of the error? Thansk.

```js
async function getData( url, rank="-1" ){

  var obj ;

  let source = CancelToken.source();
  setTimeout(() => {
    source.cancel();
  }, 20000);

  await axios
  .get( url ,  { cancelToken: source.token, timeout: 20000 })
  
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.status === 200){
      const html = response.data;
      const $ = cheerio.load(html);

      obj = {
        rank: rank ,
        url: url,
        title: title = $('title').text(),
        keywords: keywords = $("meta[name='Keywords']").attr('content'),
        description: description = $("meta[name='Description']").attr('content'),
        h1: Array.from($('h1 ')).map(a => $(a).text() ),
        h2: Array.from($('h2 ')).map(a => $(a).text() ),
        status: 0
      }

    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {

    if (error.code === "ECONNRESET") {
            console.log("Timeout occurs");
            // return;
    }
    
  });

  if (! obj){
    obj = {
      rank: rank,
      url: url,
      status: 1
    }
  }

  return obj ;

}

// calling the above function in batch something like this 
// I doubt following code HAS the problem but just in case 

... // some code here 

promises = [];
websitelists_obj["url"].forEach((item, i) => {
  
  promises.push(

    function(){
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("Started:", item)
        data = getData(websitelists_obj["url"][i], websitelists_obj["rank"][i])
        resolve(
          data
        )
      })
      .then((data) => { console.log("Completed:", item); return data; })
    }
  )
});

... // some code here 

while (promises.length) {
  array = promises.splice(0, 20).map(f => f());
  result = await Promise.all( array );
  obj = obj.concat(result);
}
```